# How to collect and pass b3 propagation headers in grpc client request using opentracing api?

Tags: grpc, istio, grpc-java, opentracing, distributed-tracing

I was using https://github.com/opentracing-contrib/java-grpc with jaegar tracer for enabling tracing in my grpc client program. Now I would like to use istio service mesh to handle tracing in server side. https://istio.io/latest/docs/tasks/observability/distributed-tracing/overview/ .
So the grpc client now needs to send the appropriate tracing HTTP headers along with each grpc client request so that istio can send those metrics to Jaegar. Does anyone have a working example of fetching the trace span information in grpc client and include the corresponding b3 propagation headers in a grpc client request?

Following http headers need to be passed in a java/C# grpc client request :

- x-request-id
- x-b3-traceid
- x-b3-spanid
- x-b3-parentspanid
- x-b3-sampled
- x-b3-flags
- x-ot-span-context

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at the [OpenTelemetry-Java-Instrumentation](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation) project. It can provide automated tracing of your application without needing to write custom code. It uses an instrumentation agent that runs in the JVM beside your application.

```
java -javaagent:path/to/opentelemetry-javaagent-all.jar \
     -jar myapp.jar
```

It supports [exporting metrics to Jaeger](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#jaeger-exporter)

It also supports [propagating headers to downstream requests](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation#propagator).

They have just added support for [b3-multi headers](https://github.com/open-telemetry/opentelemetry-java-instrumentation/pull/1647) so a new release should be available in the coming days